# Disable linebreaks in \texttt while using underscore package

Tags: typewriter, underscore

The `\texttt` normally does not lead to automatic hyphenation or linebreaks. However, it apparently does when using the `underscore` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nohyphen]{underscore}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam diam \texttt{_nonumynonumy} eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\end{document}
```

Results in [image]

The underscore is displayed in the first line, and the rest in the second line. Without the `[nohyphen]` option, it even adds a hyphen. I need the underscore package, because otherwise LaTeX only allows `_` in math mode.

**How can I disable line-breaking and still use underscores in `\texttt`?**

Comment: why not use `\_`? Is it too much text with `_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's wanted. After the underscore, `\usc@dischyph` is inserted, which is, with the `nohyphen` option, `\discretionary{}{}{}` (it would be `\-` without the option).

You can change the meaning of `\usc@dischyph`, so no line break will be allowed after an underscore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nohyphen]{underscore}

\makeatletter
\def\usc@dischyph{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
diam \texttt{_nonumynonumy} eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\end{document}
```

[image]